# Creating graphs for both WP7 & WP8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, graph, windows-phone-8

My question is really: Is there an easy way to create graphs in windows phone? (Either in-built or for free)

Could you tell me of any using statements I need to add

Links would be helpful (I couldn't find many myself)

And a basic how-to would be excellent!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lot's of libraries that provide charts for Phone 7 and 8

- http://www.infragistics.com/products/windows-phone/features/sparkline/ (Paid)
- https://github.com/ailon/amCharts-Quick-Charts (free)
- http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-phone/overview/all-controls/chart.aspx (Paid)

Answer (score 2):

The Telerik RadControls produce great graphs - http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-phone.aspx

They also have a WP App that showcases their controls - http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/telerik-examples/fd55f526-d6f7-df11-9264-00237de2db9e

Answer (score 1):

The Telerik RadControls are not free but they are by far, 100%, the best tools on the market. You can get them for free though if you have a couple apps published.

Go to http://www.Dvlup.com and sign up for a free Nokia Developer Account. Link in your developer account and it will import the apps you have made. Then you can submit apps you have made to the challenges they have on there.

As you can see [here](http://www.dvlup.com/Rewards) you can get a Nokia Premium Account Token for 1000pts which is VERY easy to get. With that token you get a free Windows PHone Developer account ($100 value) and a slew of other things like support tokens, Buddy API calls ect. I heard on the [Windows Developer Show](http://windowsdevelopershow.com/) That you also get a free set of RadControls with this token right now also.

Comment: Thanks, ill bear that in mind, but all I'm looking for is a basic free graph plotter, thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Also, other than those listed above, there is a Sparrow Toolkit.

> Sparrow Toolkit a set of Data Visualization controls(Chart, Gauge,BulletGraph and Sparkline) with lot of flexibility, performance, faster and more efficient.

http://sparrowtoolkit.codeplex.com/